# I can see a recent blockchain.info "confirmed" transaction in a shared wallet, but I do not have a balance?

Tags: blockchain.info

I sent 1 BTC to a shared wallet address (15wGmQqaYHhBqB6bEFvrXz4CJGNeBhQkmv) at blockchain.info. It gave me a transaction id e76ccebaaf5bf63762829a92f31a065bc4c5d623df18a79626f4276d536a625e and I can see the transaction, however the "balance" is not reflected in my wallet anywhere. What gives? I have done this successfully before and it was fast and easy. TIA

Comment: Can you clarify which wallet you use? blockchain.info does not offer shared wallets, so I'm not sure how it relates to this. Also note the later transaction that spends from this address, it could be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you asked this question before or after transaction ae751e14246b4287e44196ec6db01e656872dd7dc3cfb68b44e931a27c431f95 happened. In that transaction, the 1 BTC associated with 15wGmQqaYHhBqB6bEFvrXz4CJGNeBhQkmv is spent, thus there are now no coins associated with it. The balance shouldn't be reflected anywhere because it is zero.

Comment: Because it is a shared wallet in the question, the balacne tracker per address is not the balance tracker per user. Shared web wallets (like ones used by exchanges) keep intenral bookkeeping of the per-user balance in the database. When some user spends Bitcoins, they are taken from any address of any incoming transaction. This makes it possible to make internal transactions for free (outside blockchain).